# How to use a certain sonar server in sonar-maven-plugin

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I've successfully built up a SonarQube server, and I wrote several custom rules to review the code. Now, I can use the server and custom rule with Jenkins and with Maven only when the code is on the same server.

My question is when I develop maven project on another computer, and I want to use maven build or maven install, how can I still use the certain SonarQube server? Simply add plugins in the pom.xml can't use the SonarQube server I established, and the custom rules I developed are also not taken into effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [in the docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-InitialSetup), you only need to make sure the address of your SonarQube server is available to the analysis. Beyond that, you should provide the token of a user with analysis permissions (and 'create project' permissions if the project doesn't already exist) and analyze away.

Of course, this pre-supposes that your SQ server is visible on your network.

Comment: Can I just simply modify pom.xml file to add sonar-maven-plugin? Since there are lots of people in my team, I can't modify the configure file of all of them.

Comment: Individual team members shouldn't be pushing analyses to the server. If they do, you get into a last-saved-wins situation.